# Not able to login in Ubuntu box with root password

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, login

I have ubuntu 10.04 on my system. I run

```
apt-get install csh
```

and try to change the shell by

```
chsh -s
```

When I try to log into the system with ssh, I can't login with any account except for one, and when I try to change the user:

```
su - root
```

it is showing:

> Cannot execute c: no such file or directory

I looked in the `/etc/passwd` file for a root account the "shell" field there is `C` written instead of `/bin/sh`

How do I restore the settings?

Comment: Root logins are disallowed on Ubuntu by default. Use `sudo` from your "main" account to run privileged commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo -i /bin/sh` to get a working root shell, then change the `C` in root's `/etc/passwd` to `/bin/csh` with e.g. `vim` or `nano`.

*Add:*  If you're not in `sudoers`, you can also use `su -s /bin/sh`.